# extracting info from database to html page error

Tags: php, database, authentication

i'm very new to PHP so i apologize if this is a simple fix but i'm experiencing a weird issue. I've created a website that uses facebook authentication. once they login, their information gets stored in a database I've created. i then created some functions that display the users facebook image and name on the profile page of my website. problem is sometimes it shows, and other times i receive this error. "notice: undefined index: fbid in /PATH/ on line 132". Here is the code.

```
<div id="userInfo" class="userInfo">
<h1> <?php
$dbHost     = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "root";
$dbName     = "facebooklogin";


$conn = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);


if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name, picture FROM users WHERE 
oauth_uid = '".$_SESSION['fbid']."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo " ". $row["first_name"]." ". $row["last_name"]."";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?></h1>
```

userData.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbConfig.php';


$userData = json_decode($_POST['userData']);
if(!empty($userData)){
$oauth_provider = $_POST['oauth_provider'];
$_SESSION['fbid'] = $userData->id;
var_dump($_SESSION);

$prevQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE oauth_provider = 
'".$oauth_provider."' AND oauth_uid = '".$userData->id."'";

$prevResult = $db->query($prevQuery);
if($prevResult->num_rows > 0){ 

    $query = "UPDATE users SET first_name = '".$userData-
>first_name."', last_name = '".$userData->last_name."', email = 
'".$userData->email."', gender = '".$userData->gender."', locale = 
'".$userData->locale."', picture = '".$userData->picture->data->url."', 
link = '".$userData->link."', modified = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' 
WHERE oauth_provider = '".$oauth_provider."' AND oauth_uid = 
'".$userData->id."'";
    $update = $db->query($query);
}else{

    $query = "INSERT INTO users SET oauth_provider = 
'".$oauth_provider."', oauth_uid = '".$userData->id."', first_name = 
'".$userData->first_name."', last_name = '".$userData->last_name."', 
email = '".$userData->email."', gender = '".$userData->gender."', 
locale = '".$userData->locale."', picture = '".$userData->picture-
>data->url."', link = '".$userData->link."', created = '".date("Y-m-d 
H:i:s")."', modified = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."'";
    $insert = $db->query($query);
}
}

?>
```

Comment: seems that you simply don't have the variable $_SESSION['fbid']  when you do the query

Comment: thank you. can u please elaborate where i identify the variable?

Comment: I elaborated it in my answer, was it useful?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have the variable set when you use it in the query.

Check it before the query, like:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['fbid'])) {
$sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name, picture FROM users WHERE 
oauth_uid = '".$_SESSION['fbid']."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql); } else { 
// not logged in
}
```

To check the values of $_SESSION,  just do a var_dump($_SESSION) and you can see what is set.